# Как сдвинуть кнопку в html

Tags: html

```html
<button class="button-td" style="align:right">
топ демонов
  </button>
```

Не работает align:right

Comment: CSS-свойства align не существует и никогда не существовало

Answer (score 2):

Если вам нужно расположить кнопку справа относительно родительского блока, то например так:

```html
<button class="button-td" style="float: right">
    test
</button>
```

Но такой подход для позиционирования элементов применяется все реже, в частности из-за непредсказуемого поведения и сложности поддержки. Более гибкий способ - flex. Один из способов решить проблему с их помощью:

```html
<div class="wrap" style="display:flex; flex-direction: column; width: 100%;">
  <button class="button-td" style="align-self: end">
        test
    </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Наимение энергозатратный вариант - это обернуть `<button></button>` в `<div></div>` и `<div></div>`задать свойство text-align: right;

```css
.wrapper {
text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<button>топ демонов</button>
</div>
```